# Concurrent LRU Set

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, concurrency, guava

I have a program which, at some point persist a blob in a blob store.
For a given blob, a hash is used as an identifier derived always from the same algorithm, so when two blobs are identical, their BlobID are identical.

Persisting a blob is slow.
To make things worse, the program is used to put the same blob several times in a short time-frame (few seconds).

My initial idea was to use a concurrent set to keep track of what have been put in the blob store.
Sadly it will create a memory leak.

I'm looking for a kind of concurrent LRU (Least Recently Used) set in Java.
Is there such data structure? or can I build one with existing libraries? (such as Guava)

Comment: LinkedHashMap has removeEldestEntry, can be used as poor man's LRU.

Comment: Can you use Guava's cache with a removal listener? It depends on how you plan on using it, e.g. if you need LRU traversal.

Comment: It sounds like it's not necessarily that you need LRU so much as you need _any_ kind of intelligent caching.

Comment: It's not really caching *per se*, it's more a way to ensure an operation is done only once. The LRU is an optimisation to avoid OOM.